# Getting a value from a table in a materialize css modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, materialize

I have a table with values from database an a button to launch a modal and get values but when i click on the button, the modal doesn't launch. here is the php script

```
<div class="row">
    <table class="centered responsive-table striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th data-field="id">Utilisateur</th>
                <th data-field="price">Role</th>
                <th data-field="action">Action</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach (listeUtilisateursTotal() as $utilisateur):
                echo '

                <tr>
                <td data-field="pseudo_utilisateur">'.$utilisateur->username.'</td>
                <td data-field="role_utilisateur">'.nomRoleUtilisateur($utilisateur->userable_id).'</td>
                <td data-field="action">
                <input type="button" class="edit_data btn orange " value="editer" name="editer" id="'.$utilisateur->id.'" />
                </td>

            </tr>';
            endforeach;

            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

and here is the modal i want to launch

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal  modal-fixed-footer">
<div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Editer l'utilisateur</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="submit" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat btn orange "
        value="Modifier" />
</div>
```

and here is the javascript code

```
   <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function () {
                $('.modal').modal();
                $('#modal1').openModal;
                });                
            });
    </script>
```

I  want to click on the button in the table and get the id in the modal
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add class `modal-trigger` to the modal trigger button in your `PHP` code.

Also, specify `data-toggle` and `data-target` with any extra `data-*` attributes you want to use in the modal. For reference, markup your trigger button as shown in following example.

If you want to pass data to modal then you need to pass options object having `ready` property set to callback function to the `modal` method in the initialisation code as shown below. Inside callback function you have access to both `trigger` and `modal`. Check [documentation](http://materializecss.com/modals.html) to learn more.

Here is a working example.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.modal').modal({
    ready: function(modal, trigger) {
      // Do whatever you want to do with your modal and trigger button
      // For example here 'id' and 'data-id' attributes of trigger are displayed in modal
      modal.find('#trigger-id').text(trigger.attr('id'));
      modal.find('#attr-data-id').text(trigger.data('id'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Materialize CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Trigger Button -->
<button class="edit_data btn orange modal-trigger" id="'.$utilisateur->id.'" data-id="extra" data-toggle="modal" data-target="modal1">Editor</button>
 
<!-- Modal Structure -->
<div id="modal1" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <h4>My Modal</h4>
    <p>The 'id' of trigger is: <strong id="trigger-id"></strong></p>
    <p>The 'data-id' attribute of trigger is: <strong id="attr-data-id"></strong></p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="#!" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat">Dismiss</a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery and Materialize JS -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't have thé values in modal

Comment: Which values are you talking about?

Comment: The modal launches. But the trigger-id doesn't show the value

Comment: In above example trigger button id is set to a `PHP` object property, which is here being treated as a `String` and the modal is displaying as expected. If no id is being displayed in modal, then in your `PHP` code, verify that `$utilisateur->id` has value.

Comment: I have tried with static values but still not working

Comment: Run the code snippet above and see this is getting the `id` attribute properly inside modal. You may be doing something wrong. Test with exact same code as above. Still not working? Post full code you're trying with.

Comment: it works. thanks. i've forgotten a script somewher and it was the problem

Answer (score 0):

first set onclick attribute in your button and pass your id to your function like this

```
<input type="button" on-click="trigger(<?php echo $utilisateur->id; ?>)" class="edit_data btn orange " value="editer" name="editer" id="'.$utilisateur->id.'" />
```

this is your modal. i am supposing that you want to show your utilisateur id in p tag with class utilisateur_id and i have done in input field also

```
<div id="modal1" class="modal  modal-fixed-footer">
<div class="modal-content">
    <h4>Editer  l'utilisateur</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="row">
            <p class="utilisateur_id"></p>
            <input type="text" class="utilisateur_id_input">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <input type="submit" class="modal-action modal-close waves-effect waves-green btn-flat btn orange " value="Modifier"/>
</div>
```

now create toogle function in javascript and from their set value in input field through javascript

```
function toogle(id){
   //this will log you id in console. see console id your id is coming or not
   console.log(id);
   $( ".utilisateur_id" ).text(id); //this will set utilisateur id in p tag

   //if you want to set value of input then you can do like this
   $(".utilisateur_id_input").val(id);

   //show your model
    $('.modal').modal();
    $('#modal1').openModal;

}
```

from function you can set value of input field (create input field in your model and add its value from function) using javascript

Comment: i use materializecss

Comment: if confused feel free to ask i will be available after some time

Comment: i use it like this<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $(document).on('click', '.edit_data', function () {

            $('.modal').modal();
            $('#modal1').modal('show');
            $('#modal1').modal('hide');
            $('#modal1').openModal();


            });



        });


</script> but it doesn't work

Comment: i'm not good at javascript, please can you try a script i will follow. thanks